# PHP, getting content of a .txt file, want to keep enters, tabs and spaces

Tags: php, parsing, dom, enter

I`m getting the content of a webpage saved in a text file with: PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser.
Saving this into a text file. Next I want to get the content that is between pre and /pre. (with html brackets)

(only if you`re curious, I want just the info of a music tab, fe: http://www.guitaretab.com/p/pink-floyd/14683.html)

I do this with:

```
    $first_step = explode( '<pre>' , $page );
    $second_step = explode("</pre>" , $first_step[1] ); 
    echo $second_step[0];
```

The problem I`m having is that in my .txt file, the text is formatted well, with chords above lyrics with spaces / tabs and enters like this:

```
 G                        C
 Heavy hung the canopy of blue
 G                        C
 Shade my eyes and I can see you
```

The echo line results in everything standing in 1 line without enters etc. I don`t know what I can do to prevent this. Thank you if you can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

this will echo without pre tags

```
$pos = strpos($page, '<pre>')+5;
$length = strpos($page, '</pre>') - $pos;
echo strip_tags(substr($page, $pos, $length));
```

this will echo with pre tags

```
$pos = strpos($page, '<pre>')+5;
$length = strpos($page, '</pre>') - $pos;
echo '<pre>' . strip_tags(substr($page, $pos, $length) . '<pre>';
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that doesnt work for this. 
What I see it does that instead of my browser word wrapping the entire string, it is just one line now giving me a horizontal scroll bar. Any other idea?

Comment: What you post does make sense, but doesnt work... I`m getting the right amount of text that is between PRE. But no enters. I`ll try to apply emil`s solution tomorrow. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use php pregreplace

```
preg_replace(/\s+/g, ' ',$string);
```

Comment: Going to try it, reading some first how preg replace works because just this is giving a: syntax error, unexpected '/', expecting ')'